# Configuration of SonarQube SQL Server 2012 db documentation error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sonarqube

I may be the only person who has actually read the "requirements" but it specifically states that for SQL Server 2012:

(warning) Collation must be case-sensitive (CS) and accent-sensitive (AS)

UTF-8 and Language to English. (this is for all databases) The UTF-8 is not an option for SQL Server 2012 but I know we can set that elsewhere.

My DBA (who is setting up the database for us) says there are no "English" options for collation and accent-sensitive-ness.

Refer to the page http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements to see what I'm talking about.

Should the instructions be updated or am I missing something?

Comment: Just as an add on.  If you do have it set to case sensitive, the case of the database name in the connection string must exactly match the case of the database name. ie:  sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dbsrv209/SonarQUBE;useNTLMv2=true;SelectMethod=Cursor;domain=mydomain.org;

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the correct answer to this is something like: "SQL_Latin1_general_CP1_CS_AS" which the dba found after telling me there wasn't anything like what I was asking for.